# I am getting the error of "Cannot read property 'innerText' of undefined" at Array.forEach (<anonymous>) at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous>

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, typeerror

I know that this error comes because here "cardTxt" is not a string. I knew it by checking with typeof syntax. But Why this can't be a string. I am unable to findout. I have used bootstrap for styling here. Someone please suggest me. I am really stuck in it.

```
let search = document.getElementById('searchTxt');
search.addEventListener("input", function(){

    let inputVal = search.value.toLowerCase();

    let noteCards = document.getElementsByClassName('noteCard');
    Array.from(noteCards).forEach(function(element){
        let cardTxt = element.getElementsByTagName("p")[0].innerText;
        if(cardTxt.includes(inputVal)){
            element.style.display = "block";
        }
        else{
            element.style.display = "none";
        }

    })
```

Comment: If you also post `html` code, that will be helpful to find the issue easily

Comment: "*I know that this error comes because here "cardTxt" is not a string.*" No, the error is to do with being **unable to get the 'innerText' because the element you're looking for is undefined** (i.e. the error message!)... in other words, `element.getElementsByTagName("p")[0]` is not returning anything. But without seeing the HTML this is working on, we can't help you find out why it can't be found.

Answer (score 1):

The only explanation is that the element passed in has no p tags in it while you are trying to access index 0 of an empty array. Try

```
console.log(element.getElementsByTagName("p"));
```

and see if the output is empty.